# Exception trigger on column update laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I working in laravel 4.2 version and I am using chunk method in larval eloquent when I run my query then I always receive the column name instead of update.

Here is my method to update table column

```
$result = Message::where('message_to', '=', $userData['id'])
                    ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                    ->orwhere(function($query) use($userData) {
                        $query->where('message_to', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                        ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['id']);
                    })->chunk(100,function($messages) use($userData){
                       foreach($messages as $msg){
                         $update = empty($msg->deleted_one) ? ['deleted_one'=>$userData['id']] : ['deleted_two'=>$userData['id']];
                         $msg->update($update);
                       } 
                    });
```

Below is the response that I always receive when I run this query

```
{"success":"false","message":"deleted_two"}
```

In message I receive the column name.

Comment: Where is that `response` constructed? Show that code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy response not constructed control directly goes to catch method in controller from where method is called.

Comment: Can we see that?

Comment: what is this line about `$update = empty($msg->deleted_one) ? ['deleted_one'=>$userData['id']] : ['deleted_two'=>$userData['id']];`?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi this line simply make the updation array